# How to select Principle components based on proportion of variation explained dynamically

Tags: r, pca

Suppose i have the following dataframe of PCs

```
pcdf
   PrinComp Standard deviation Proportion of Variance Cumulative Proportion
1       PC1         2.09181795                0.27348               0.27348
2       PC2         1.45030065                0.13146               0.40494
3       PC3         1.19493344                0.08924               0.49418
4       PC4         1.02857740                0.06612               0.56031
5       PC5         1.00286501                0.06286               0.62317
6       PC6         0.98925935                0.06116               0.68433
7       PC7         0.95393902                0.05687               0.74121
8       PC8         0.93883040                0.05509               0.79629
9       PC9         0.89496910                0.05006               0.84635
10     PC10         0.80537287                0.04054               0.88689
11     PC11         0.71167409                0.03166               0.91855
12     PC12         0.69485069                0.03018               0.94872
13     PC13         0.64756330                0.02621               0.97493
14     PC14         0.49804019                0.01550               0.99044
15     PC15         0.38854373                0.00944               0.99987
16     PC16         0.04552681                0.00013               1.00000
```

Now i would like to select PCs based on the criteria:
`I should have atleast have 5 PCs and Cumulative Proportion should be >0.75`(cut of threshold should be dynamically done)

What i mean is that whenever i run PCA on any datasets and i get the PCs, i whould be able to subset fewer PCs which is able to have proportion of variation explained not less than 75% but also taking care that no of PCs are not less than 5....

Would like help in this nagging problem....

Comment: this? `pcdf$PrinComp[cumsum(pcdf$ProportionofVariance) >= 0.75][1:5]`

Answer (score 0):

To do this dynamically, I would first consider using a `lag` function from the `dplyr` package.

```
pcdf.I <- pcdf %>%
          mutate(lag.cp  = lag(`Cumulative Proportion`, 1)) %>%
          mutate(I.75    = ifelse(`Cumulative Proportion` >=.75 & lag.cp <= .75, 1, 0)

if(min(which(pcdf.I[I.75 == 1])) < 5){

     pcdf.I <- pcdf.I[1:5,]

} else {

     pcdf.I[1:(which(pcdf.I[1:pcdf.i$I.75 == 1)), ]

}
```

This set of steps first creates a way to determine between what two row indices is `Cumulative Proportion ~ .75` between by first `lag`ing `Cumulative Proportion` then creating an indicator that determines at which point is .75 between `Cumulative Proportion`and `lag.cp`. Because they are both equalities (`Cumulative Proportion` is equated as `>=` and `lag.cp` is equated as `<=`), there is a chance that if `Cumulative proportion = .75`, it may be double counted. We resolve this in the `if` statement. The end result is either a table of 5 rows based on `pcdf` or a table of "n" rows based on when `pcdf.i ~ .75`.